# opencart redirect same page after login

Tags: opencart

i am new in the opencart. now i have make some category restriction means user must have to login to see that category. so when user click on that category if he is not logged in then he will redirect to the login page. The above process is working fine
now once i login i want to redirect to the same category page.
when i come to the login page i can see the value of "$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']" is as i want

```
site.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62
```

now as i read the tutorial online then told me to change some code in this file "project\catalog\controller\account\login.php"
i have replace the below code

```
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
```

To

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
                    $this->redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
                } else {
                    $this->redirect(HTTPS_SERVER . 'index.php?route=account/account');
                }
```

when i come to the login page i have right link in the HTTP_REFERER but when i click on the login then it become the login link in referer. so how can i set that ?

can you suggest me how can i do this ?
i am confused about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after the login request (which shall be POST) the form is submitted to the same URL thus the previous referrer is replaced by the login page. It goes like this:

- referrer when redirected to login: `site.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=62`
- referrer after login request: `site.com/index.php?route=account/login`

Therefore store Your current URL into the session within the category controller before You are redirecting to login:

```php
$this->session->data['redirect_after_login'] = "<CURRENT URL GOES HERE>";
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login'));
```

Now in login controller after successful login action check whether the session variable exists and if yes redirect to it:

```php
if(!empty($this->session->data['redirect_after_login'])) {
    $url = $this->session->data['redirect_after_login'];
    unset($this->session->data['redirect_after_login']);
    $this->redirect($this->session->data['redirect_after_login']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Before redirecting user to a login page you can set a `$this->session->data['redirect']` variable to an URL where user will be redirected upon successful login.

The following code, for example, will redirect visitor to the list of addresses after successful login:

```
$this->session->data['redirect'] = $this->url->link('account/address', '', 'SSL');
$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'));
```

2. Or you can modify the catalog/controller/account/login.php like this.

A. Change

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {  
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
}
```

to

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {  
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));
}elseif(!isset($this->session->data['redirect']) && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    $this->session->data['redirect'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

B. And change

$this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'));

to

```
if(!empty($this->session->data['redirect'])){
    $redirect = $this->session->data['redirect'];
    unset($this->session->data['redirect']);
    $this->redirect($redirect);
}else{
    $this->redirect($this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL')); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created an extension for this on the Opencart.

https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=13998

It has 3 features:
Page after login.
Page after logout.
Plus Strict Login.